# Phillippine passport with New Zealand tourist visa. Do I need transit visa in Australia en route New Zealand?

Tags: australia, new-zealand, filipino-citizens, transit-visas

I hold a Philippine passport traveling to New Zealand in transit at Melbourne, Australia. I have New Zealand tourist visa. Do I need to get transit visa in Australia for a 3 hours in transit ?

Answer (score 6):

Citizens of Philippines don't need a transit visa if the following criteria are met:

- enter Australia by aircraft
- hold a confirmed onward booking to leave
  Australia to travel to a third country on the same or another
  aircraft within 8 hours of arrival in Australia
- hold documentation
  necessary to enter the country of destination and
- not need to leave
  the airport transit lounge except to continue their journey

Source: [Do I need a visa to transit through Australia?](http://www.border.gov.au/Lega/Lega/Form/Immi-FAQs/do-i-need-a-visa-to-transit-through-australia)